# django - Get the exact GET url that was used to call a django view (including params)

Tags: python, django

I have a view which accepts GET params (accessible via the `request.GET` and that are present in the uri)

Inside the view I want to get the exact uri that was used to call that view maintaining order

Example:

If a call was made to `http://best.site.ever/?this=that&that=this` I want to be able to fetch it in the view

```
def best_view_ever(request):
    calling_uri = get_calling_uri(request)
    calling_uri # this should be http://best.site.ever/?this=that&that=this
```

Is this achievable in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django request objects have a helper method available, called [`build_absolute_uri`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri):

```
request.build_absolute_uri()
```

Answer (score 0):

`build_absolute_uri` method of request object would be helpful here

```
def get_calling_uri(request):
    return request.build_absolute_uri()

def best_view_ever(request):
    calling_uri = get_calling_uri(request)
    print calling_uri # this should be http://best.site.ever/?this=that&that=this
```